# iterating over a json array to fill a dropdown - angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, angularjs, dropdown

I have a json array from a json response of this nature

```
data {"success":true,"errorCode":0,"data":["kkkk-kkkk 1","oooo-ooooo 2"]}
```

1. Item 1 is expected to be >>> `kkkk-kkkk 1`
2. Item 2 is expected to be >>> `oooo-ooooo 2`

in angular script controller I am doing this to push the array into the html view

```
else if (res.status == 200) { 
    $scope.partners = []; 
    var myJSON = res.data; 
    console.log("data" + JSON.stringify(res.data));
    angular.forEach(myJSON, function (item) { 

    $scope.activities.push(item);
```

I want to get the json arrays to fill a dropdown of this is a challenge

```
<select ng-model="act" formcontrol class="ui fluid dropdown ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" required>
  <option ng-repeat="a in activities" value="{{a}}">{{a}}</option>
</select>
```

Please assist

Comment: Why don't you assign `res.data.data` directly to `$scope.activities`?

Comment: yes that wont also solve the drop problem

Comment: What do you mean by _drop problem_?

Comment: this >>> <option ng-repeat="a in activities" value="{{a}}">{{a}}</option>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you are iterating the wrong array, you are iterating the object instead.

Because in your code:

```
console.log("data" + JSON.stringify(res.data));
```

Will give you:

```
data {"success":true,"errorCode":0,"data":["kkkk-kkkk 1","oooo-ooooo 2"]}
```

So you need to store `res.data.data` in your `myJSON` variable, or the best would be to assign this array directly in your `$scope.activities`:

```
$scope.activities = res.data.data;
```

And in your HTML:

```
<select ng-model="act" formcontrol class="ui fluid dropdown ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid"  ng-options="option for option in activities"required>
</select>
```

Comment: that has been done so how how I populate the dropdown with it

Comment: upon clicking the dropdown

Comment: Please show us a live demo so we can see the whole code and the issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178212/discussion-between-rocket-and-chsdk).

Answer (score 0):

use **ng-options**

```
ng-options="item as item for item in activities"
```